# Logging to the same flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, migration

I have a SSIS migration solution, which I have been asked to log from. The log would have a lines from SQL selects. for example,

SELECT 'People who have invalid statuses'
SELECT ID, StatusID FROM Person

Is there a way to pipe those results somehow into a flat file? But also, have the same component 'copied?' in all my packages, in various different places to log different actions, on the same way as above?

Or, do I need to Select the results into a ExecSQL component, and then have the output to a flat file component? Problem there is I will have different result sets into the same component. I just need to log lines to a log file, and allow different components to use the same mechanism to log.

is there a pattern to do this?

Comment: can you please give one example..  if i understand your problem correctly you need 'People who have invalid statuses' upended in log if it is  correct then use derived column...

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to ask.  What have you done so far, and what about it is not working?